# Javascript solo funciona en la misma Pagina

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con unas rutinas de Javascript que solo me funcionan en la misma pagina, dejan de funcionar cuando las pongo en otro archivo en el cual tengo otras rutinas de Javascript que funcionan de manera normal, la primera funcion me muestra un tooltip en unos botones submit, la otra es una funcion simple que me cambia las minusculas a mayusculas, de esta manera las tengo en la pagina:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
         });

    function mayus(e) {
        e.value = e.value.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
```

cuando los pongo en un archivo p utilitarios.js no me las reconoce. dicho archivo lo incluyo en la pagina de la siguiente manera:

```
<script src="views/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="views/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="views/js/utilitarios.js"></script>
```

Que debo hacer para que me funcione adecuadamente??.

Comment: Verifique que no tenga errores _(404)_ en consola con respecto a la ruta del archivo.

Comment: Joel acabo de revisar me sale el siguiente error :   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at utilitarios.js:2

Comment: Agregué el código en el orden que tiene agregados en su `HTML` , el error es posible porque no se añadió correctamente `Jquery`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $` esto es causado porque se requiere `Jquery`, debes importar primero la librería `Jquery`

Comment: Añade el error que te aparece a la pregunta, no lo dejes en los comentarios

Comment: Agrega la importación de Jquery, antes que cualquier otro archivo .js

Comment: el problema era el cache del chrome, no me actualizaba el codigo que modificaba. gracias y siento no haberme explicado adecuadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Has mencionado este error en los comentarios

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at utilitarios.js:2.`

Es posible que no te este reconociendo el simbolo $? esto puede ser como bien ha mencionado el usuario "Cesar Romero" a que no tienes importada la libreria o la ruta la has escrito mal.

Comment: O el orden no es el correcto